# Understanding ETF grammar and abstract syntax trees

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, context-free-grammar, parse-tree

I have attached the problem below with the answer. My problem is that I can't understand it. Can you provide an overall explanation in detail about parse trees and ETF grammar by deriving the first expression?[image]

Just try to explain the first expression, a+b/c+d. I think it's not that hard, but I just haven't been able to find the right resources to understand this. Can u also provide resources that explain ETF grammar?. If you don't want to give an explanation, it would be nice if at least you can point out some resource to understand this. As an strategy, I think it's better to build the parse tree first and then convert it to AST.

Answer (score 1):

This is a careless question. There is no reason *a priori* why the ETF grammar needs to correspond to any particular AST.  It's true that it's easiest for a parser based on the EFT grammar to build an AST with conventional precedence rules. And it's also true that a left-recursive grammar like this makes it easiest to implement left-associative operations in the ASTs.

But these are big assumptions that the question ought to state explicitly. To fully specify the problem, you'd need to give an *attribute grammar* that produces the ASTs, not just a bare grammar.

An attribute grammar would specify how AST nodes are built:

```
E_a -> E_b + T  { E_a.ast = makeNode('+', E_b.ast, T.ast) }
E -> T          { E.ast = T.ast }
...
F -> i          { F.ast = makeLeaf(i) }
```

So if we make the assumption of a typical attribute grammar, then the structure of the EFT grammar implies a precedence of operations.

The operator at the "top" of the grammar - derived directly from the start symbol - corresponds to least precedence. You can think of it this way:

```
E -> E + T | T
```

expands to a list of one or more `T`erms separated by `+` operators.

```
E -> T + ... + T
```

This implies that the attribute grammar constructs a left-skewed tree of terms (`T`s). Everything that goes on "within the `T`s" is higher in precedence. Those things are "bound together" with no regard for the surrounding `+`.

The corresponding AST will look like:

```
+
| \
+  T
| \
+  T
|
.
.
.
+
| \
T  T
```

In words, the expression is a sum of preceding terms (the left subtree under the root) added to the last term (the right subtree).  The successive additions occur left-to-right.  This is called a *left associative* operation. Some operations - typically exponentiation for example - have the tree skewed the other way, so operations are evaluated right-to-left. `2^3^2` means "2 raised to the 9th power" = 512 not "8 squared" = 64.

Now you can expand the terms. In your example, the first term finally expands to `a`. The second expands to `F / F` and finally to `b / c`. (This assumes that the `*` rule applies to `/` as well.)  The third term expands to `d`.  So you end up with

```
+
| \
+  T
| \
T  T
```

and this becomes

```
+__
|  \
+   d
| \  
a  /  
   |\
   b c
```

The operation `b/c` is higher in precedence than `+` because its closer to the leaves of the tree.

Parentheses override this natural precedence. The expression

```
(a + b) / c
```

expands initially with only a single term!

```
E -> T
  -> T / F
  -> F / F
```

The second factor goes to `c`. So intuitively, the tree has the form:

```
/
| \ 
F  c
```

Now the key attribute grammar rule for expanding `F` is

```
F -> ( E )  { F.ast = E.ast }
```

So we really have

```
/_______
|       \
( E )    c
```

Now `( E )` expands to an AST for `a + b` all by itself

```
/_______
|       \
+        c
| \ 
a  b
```

Note how the `+` is closer to the leaves. The parentheses have given it higher precedence than the `/`!